# Enum in constructor Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, constructor, enums

I'm create my own LOGGER, where I use an additional class for overload macro.
There is #define qlcd MacroCall(QLC::Debug), so i can use logger like this: qlcd << message;
It's ok, but when i try use qlcd("log name") i got an error. Look minimal code (no macro for simplify):

```
#include <QVariant>
#include <QDebug>

class QLC
{
public:
// Error types
enum LevelType{
    Debug=0,  // Debug
    Error=1,  // Error
    WTF = 2   // WTF???
} level;

QString logger;

// Constructors
QLC(QLC::LevelType l)
    :level(l), logger(":")
{}

QLC(QLC::LevelType l, QString log)
    :level(l), logger(log)
{}

// OPERATOR <<
QLC& operator<<(const QVariant var){
    qDebug() << "(" + QString::number(level) + ")" << logger << var;
}
};

class MacroCall
{
QLC::LevelType level;
public:
MacroCall()
    :level(QLC::Debug){}

MacroCall(int i)
    :level(QLC::WTF){}

MacroCall(QLC::LevelType l)
    :level(l){}

QLC operator()(){
    return QLC(level);
}
QLC operator()(QString log){
    return QLC(level, log);
}
};

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
MacroCall()("WorkLog") << "No level, yes logname";
MacroCall(QLC::Error)() << "No logname, yes level";

MacroCall a(QLC::Error);
a("WorkLog") << "Logname and level at different lines";

// GET READY!
// INT as level and logname:
MacroCall(2)("WorkLog") << "WTF?? It works!";

//MacroCall(QLC::WTF)("NotWorkLog") << "It's not work!!!!!!";
// NOT WORK: error: invalid use of qualified-name 'QLC::WTF'
// Qt 4.8.3

return 0;
}
```

Comment: qDebug() is not a "debugger"

Comment: i mean logger XD, thx))

Comment: When you get "an error", you need to exactly describe what the error is in order to make it easy for other people to help you.

Comment: I describe it in a code: NOT WORK: error: invalid use of qualified-name 'QLC::WTF'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

> MacroCall(QLC::WTF)("NotWorkLog")

is interpreted as declaration of a variable:

```
MacroCall QLC::WTF("NotWorkLog")
```

Example:

```
class A
{
    public:
    enum E {
        x=1
    };

    public:
    A(E) {}
    void operator()(int) const { }
};

class B {};

void f()
{
    (A(A::x))(1); // Ok
    A{A::x}(1); // Ok
    A(a)(A::x); // Ok

    A::E a; // ‘a’ has a previous declaration as ‘A a’
    A(A::x)(1); // invalid use of qualified-name ‘A::x’
    B(b)(A::x); // no matching function for call to ‘B::B(A::E)’
}
```

Comment: Indeed, the most-vexing parse strikes once again. [stmt.ambig]/1 states it can be an expression-statement or a declaration, and it's defined to be a declaration. [stmt.ambig]/2 states "Disambiguation
precedes parsing, and a statement disambiguated as a declaration may be an ill-formed declaration."

Comment: Cool chalenge! XD I fixed it by use constructor(int t){type =QLC::Types(t)} Any other ways?

Answer (score 2):

The code you gave compiles (except that the method `QLC& operator<<(const QVariant var)` has to return something), eventhough I'm not sure of how it's supposed to be used.

My guess is that your 2 classes are defined in different headers and an include is missing. Does `Macrocall` header include `QLC` header ?

Comment: No, it's whole single file. It's a minimal code, usability u can look here: https://github.com/ammaximus/QLogCat/tree/master/qlc (Current problem already fixed)